# Printing large set of images with captions and page numbers

Tags: software-rec, images, printing, caption

I would like ot take a set of ~800 jpeg images, and print them one per page with the following details:

1) One image per page.

2) Page numbers that are consecutive all the way through.

3) Single header text for the whole job -- same on every page

4) Copyright text to be displayed on every page (could be part of the header if needed)

5) Caption below each image -- this will be the file name (with .jpg removed)

6) Images must be printed in alphbetical order of file name.

I can be flexible on some of this, but most of it is needed.

I suspect that the job will have to be done in batches as I can imagein a paperjam on page 763 distroying the whole job. at the least it will have to be restartable at an arbitrary point.

The closest I have to being able to do this is adobe lightroom, that can print the images pretty much to spec, but it's page numbering seems a little nieve -- it always starts at 1, and there is no way to print only part of the job. A paper jam will actually mean restarting the job from scratch. I also can't imagine any printing infrastucture being happy with a single job of that size.

Current best idea is to print to PDF, then use acrobat to handle the chunking of the print job. at least when that goes wrong, we don't waste lots of paper.

Anyone know any suitable software?

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no experience with it. But you might want to try [scripting for Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html) or [scripting for photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html).

Comment: I think printing to PDF would be the easiest way to accomplish what you want to do, however you need PDF publishing software which isn't free(such as Acrobat Pro).